# postgresql and device in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise

I have table charts (from schema.rb):

```
create_table "charts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "glcode"
    t.integer  "gst"
    t.integer  "code",                                null: false
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "header"
    t.integer  "user"
    t.decimal  "amount_1",   precision: 10, scale: 2
    t.decimal  "amount_2",   precision: 10, scale: 2
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
end

add_index "charts", ["glcode"], name: "index_charts_on_glcode", using:     :btree
add_index "charts", ["user"], name: "index_charts_on_user", using: :btree
```

At the moment table charts contains 51 records with "user" = 0.

The table has 5 integer fields. Four from them works fine:

```
Chart.where("header = ?",0).count
(0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "charts" WHERE (header = 0)
29

Chart.where("code = ?",0).count
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "charts" WHERE (code = 0)
0

Chart.where("glcode = ?",0).count
(0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "charts" WHERE (glcode = 0)
0

Chart.where("gst = ?",0).count
(0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "charts" WHERE (gst = 0)
25
```

But one from them does not work at all:

```
Chart.where("user = ?",0).count
(0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "charts" WHERE (user = 0)
*** ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::UndefinedFunction:     ERROR:  operator does not exist: name = integer
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "charts" WHERE (user = 0)
                                              ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "charts" WHERE (user = 0)
nil
```

Migration for the table:

```
class CreateCharts < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :charts do |t|
            t.integer :glcode, index: true
            t.integer :gst
            t.integer :code, null: false
            t.string :content
            t.integer :header
            t.integer :user, index: true
            t.decimal :amount_1, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
            t.decimal :amount_2, :precision => 10, :scale => 2

            t.timestamps null: false
        end
    end
end
```

At sqlite everything worked fine. Only one that differs field "user" from others is that table "users" used in devise, but in this case it looks irrelevant. What it is - bug in postgresql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"user" is a reserved word (see the [list](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)). You could either quote the column name or change your query to

```
Chart.where(user: 0)
```

and rails will quote the column name for you